# Android: How to get x and y points of a specific item clicked on GridView

Tags: android, android-gridview, geopoints

i have a gridView. i want to display the x and y points of a specific item when an item is clicked. tnx.

Answer (score 3):

Call `getTop()`, `getLeft()` on the item. This should return `y` and `x` of that item relative to its parent.